# error while building phonegap app using ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, build, ionic-framework

I need to build an phonegap app using angularjs .
so i choose ionic framework. 
these are the steps, I have done so far.

1. set up java,ant, adt and their path.
2. install ionic using command

   npm install -g ionic
3. start ionic project uisng

   ionic
   ionic start ex1
4. add ionic platform

   ionic platform add android
5. build using command

   ionic build android

But doing building, it shows error.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Android\adt-bundle\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:932: The following error occurred
while executing this line:
C:\Android\adt-bundle\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:950: null returned: -1073741819

Total time: 11 seconds

C:\Android\fresh\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,C:\Android\fresh\pla
tforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
```

I hadn't modified any code still. and apache ant and java are also working. Why this error?

the contents in C:\Android\adt-bundle\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml is added below

```
line 930  <target name="-package-resources" depends="-crunch">
                <!-- only package resources if *not* a library project -->
line 932    <do-only-if-not-library elseText="Library project: do not package resources..." >
              <aapt executable="${aapt}"
                    command="package"
                    versioncode="${version.code}"
                    versionname="${version.name}"
                    debug="${build.is.packaging.debug}"
                    manifest="${out.manifest.abs.file}"
                    assets="${asset.absolute.dir}"
                    androidjar="${project.target.android.jar}"
                    apkfolder="${out.absolute.dir}"
                    nocrunch="${build.packaging.nocrunch}"
                    resourcefilename="${resource.package.file.name}"
                    resourcefilter="${aapt.resource.filter}"
                    libraryResFolderPathRefid="project.library.res.folder.path"
                    libraryPackagesRefid="project.library.packages"
                    libraryRFileRefid="project.library.bin.r.file.path"
                    previousBuildType="${build.last.target}"
                    buildType="${build.target}"
line 950            ignoreAssets="${aapt.ignore.assets}">
                <res path="${out.res.absolute.dir}" />
                <res path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
                <!-- <nocompress /> forces no compression on any files in assets or res/raw -->
                <!-- <nocompress extension="xml" /> forces no compression on specific file extensions in assets and res/raw -->
            </aapt>
        </do-only-if-not-library>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have solved this issue, ie the error -1073741819 . this is due to bug in aapt.exe file build-tools in sdk for windows users.

Replace the aapt.exe file with this file https://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=776290120000&name=aapt.exe.zip&token=ABZ6GAcRj6lR-sOmUyVguB0Gmf_BI4Z7Gg%3A1415016896298

for more information, Check this page

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77629